# Page not found (404) error message when using get_object_or_404 method

Tags: python, django

**thank you so much for your help.**
this is the error message i get when running the code.
*Page not found (404)*
*Request Method:    GET *
*Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/1/*
*Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:*

```
admin/
blog/ [name='post_list']
blog/ <int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/ [name='post_detail']
The current path, blog/1/, didn’t match any of these.
```

**views.py** in blog directory

```
def post_detail(request,year,month,day,post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, 
                             status=Post.Status.PUBLISHED,
                             slug=post,
                             publish__year=year,
                             publish__month=month,
                             publish__day=day
                             )
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {"post":post})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        DRAFT='DF', 'Draft'
        PUBLISHED = 'PB', 'Published'
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                              choices=Status.choices,
                              default=Status.DRAFT)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publish']
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['-publish'])]
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog:post_detail", args = [self.publish.year,
                                                   self.publish.month,
                                                   self.publish.day,
                                                   self.slug])
```

**urls.py** in mysite.urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog'))
]
```

**urls** in blog directory

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name='blog'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(),name='post_list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/', views.post_detail,name='post_detail'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL requires either a value for year, month, day, and post or no value for the list. You only gave one value, so get_object_or_404 errors (giving error 404 page not found hence its name) when trying to assign values for the slug, month, and day since no values were given in the url. Using a url like  http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2023/7/5/12 is the proper formatting, using values that correspond to your database.